# how to do conditional formatting properly here

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements

I have this piece of code that I want to check a folder for known temp files and report if folder is incomplete but only if `verbal` is defined and then `exit /b`. The problem is that the `if defined` blocks `exit /b` from happening. `exit /b` should happen if any temp files are found no matter what.

```
dir *.part *.parts *.!qb /s /b >nul 2>nul && if defined verbal echo incomplete "%cd%" && exit /b
```

Comment: `dir *.part *.parts *.!qb /s /b >nul 2>nul && (if defined verbal echo incomplete "%cd%") & exit /b`

Comment: this exits no matter what. it should not happen when no files are found

Comment: In this new code, if defined verbal then echo and exit; otherwise do nothing (not echo and not exit): `dir *.part *.parts *.!qb /s /b >nul 2>nul && (if defined verbal echo incomplete "%cd%" & exit /b`). Please, be clearer in your requests...